# Button icons: round close icon

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, button, icons

I've seen other apps are using a round icon for closing a view. The only similar icon I found is `UIBarButtonSystemItemStop`. But this presents only a rotated cross with a border (as always with buttons) around it.

I rather would like have something like a `UIButtonTypeInfoLight`. If this button is used, no border is visible. Also the icon is a round grey icon with a symbol (here i symbol) in it. Are there further icons in this style available? Neither `UIBarButtonSystemItem` nor `UIButtonType` is offering that.

I have also seen a thunderbolt icon in the style of `UIButtonTypeInfoLight`. Are these icons self made? If yes, how are they included so that no border is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These buttons are custom.

You can embed any custom view into bar using `[UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:]`.

You can use `UIButton` with `UIButtonTypeCustom` type so that you have button with no border. Also set `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` to `YES` so that button glows like info button.